# Backslash in Path

Tags: shell

I would like to know what the meaning of the backslash is when used in a path, e.g.:

```
ll /opt/deployment/release175/war-files\ files/
```

output, for example is:

```
accounting-module.war

finance-module.war
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The backslash is the [*escape* character](https://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html) to tell the shell not to interpret some special characters. In your case, it escapes the space character.

In shell, a space is normally used to split arguments. Without the backslash, your shell would interpret the space as usually. You would have 2 arguments to your `ll` call, which would probably lead to a "File or Directory not found" error.

Alternatively you could surround your argument with quotes:

```
ll /opt/deployment/release175/war-files\ files/
ll "/opt/deployment/release175/war-files files/"
ll '/opt/deployment/release175/war-files files/'
```

Backslash is also used to escape other special characters:

```
\(
\$
\{
\*
\#
\\
```

Comment: ... and under some circumstances `\!` when combined with other characters (interactive `bash` to avoid history expansion).

Answer (score 4):

In Unix/Linux (or POSIX), the backslash is an escape character.

In that particular case, the backslash is escaping white space. If it weren't there then the `ll` command would attempt to operate on:

`/opt/deployment/release175/war-files\`

and

`files/`

You can also use double or single quotes

`ll "opt/deployment/release175/war-files files/"`

`ll 'opt/deployment/release175/war-files files/'`

The backslash can also be used to escape other special characters with other commands:

`rpm -qa | postgre\*`

`grep \.regex file`

```
sed 's/\/this\/path/\/that/\/path/g'
```